# k-means Unsupervised Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am running a cluster analysis using WEKA. 
In what instances would someone use an unsupervised k-means clustering when the class is labeled?
Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY broad!  You may be better off doing some Googling on your side and watch some related YouTube videos as well.  Then, come back here with a specific question or several specific questions.  This seems more like an opinion, rather than a question.